# External library import, Gradle build issue

Tags: android, android-layout

**I tried to import this** https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout Circular layout but getting these warnings while build the project.

Warnings:

> Error:(1) No resource identifier found for attribute 'angleOffset' in
>   package 'com.aitrg.praneeth.organizer'

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/praneeth/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: You should use `app:angleOffset`, not `android:angleOffset`

Comment: I used app:angleOffset only!

Comment: How have you imported the library?

Comment: @m vai : no there is some gradle prob so I'm copied all the required classes and files and using them with in my own pakage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Got the answer with help of**  [Shvet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3981822/shvet)

--> First download the file and extract it.

--> In Android studio using import, import it as a module using Import-Module.

--> After Importing it as library go to Gradle of Module(imported file) change plug-in as library.

- *apply plugin: 'com.android.library'*

--> As library file don't have versions remove version id/name.

--> Add dependencies manually by  *compile project(':circleLayout')* or using project structure.

--> Now rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in the top viewgroup in the layout file where you are using the CircleLayout.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@android:color/white"
       app:angleOffset="90.0">

    </ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did that! bro I think there is a problem while importing the lib with gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't copy-pasting classes one by one into your project, but rather import the library as whole, downloading it and adding to your lib folder. Libraries are standalone environments with a Manifest and extra files which you might not have yourself.

However, following what you have done now, you are clearly missing some attribute files. Looking at the library, my guess is that you are missing [this one](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout/blob/master/res/values/styleable.xml). It should be in the `values` folder.

Comment: I copied along with this file and put it in values! folder only