# impossible to import android.content.res.Resources

Tags: java, android, ios, import, robovm

I can't find how to `import android.content.res.Resources;`
Here is my code:

```
package com.mycompany.fortune;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import android.content.res.Resources; //This don't work
import retrofit.http.GET;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class FortuneClient {
    private static final String API_URL = "http://www.myurl.fr";

    private interface FortuneService {
        @GET("/test.php")
        void getFortune(Callback<JsonObject> callback);
    }

    public static class OnFortuneListener {
        public void onFortune(String fortune) {
        }
    }

    private static Random rng = new Random();

    private FortuneService service;

    public FortuneClient() {
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .build();

        service = adapter.create(FortuneService.class);
    }

    public void getFortune(final OnFortuneListener listener) {
        service.getFortune(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void success(JsonObject json, Response response) {
                String test = json.getAsJsonObject("0").getAsJsonObject("title").toString();
                String test2 = json.getAsJsonObject("0").getString('title');
                listener.onFortune(test2);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                listener.onFortune(error.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**the error is**: "Error:(8, 26) Gradle: error: package android.content.res does not exist"

**What I tried:**

-Make, remake, build, clean, rebuild,

-Invalidate cache and restart,

-Verify the java/sdk/jdk positions,

-Stupid things on the gradle/xml files.

Comment: Check dis it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093607/external-library-import-gradle-build-issue/32473672#32473672

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work for me :/

Comment: are u Importing it as library??

Comment: Does any other android package works other than resources.

Comment: If you count Retrofit as a package, it works, but it's more a library than a package. The only package that android allows me to import is: android.support.annotation.*

Comment: Is this an Android Project?

Comment: Look at the tags, it's an android/ios project made with RoboVM (allows to make a java core for an ios app)

Answer (score 0):

This import `android.content.res.Resources;` //This don't work is used in your application code to access the resources. To Access any particular resource you should pass the context to this class atleast .

Comment: Could you add an example ?
If I can't import the resources, how can I access one ?